# logrotate duplicate log entry

Tags: linux, администрирование

Вопрос по-большей части не как исправить эту ошибку, а как переопределять пути к логам.

Значит существует некий сервер с **rsyslog** который принимает от кучи хостов логи и создаёт для них директории/файлы_логов по маске `/var/log/dir1/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%.log`; разумеется, есть необходимость ротировать все эти логи, этим занимается `logrotate` с примерно таким конфигом `/etc/logrotate.conf`

```
    /var/log/dir1/*/*log {
        missingok
        rotate 20
        postrotate
            /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        endscript
    }
```

Всё работает, всё отлично! Но вот допустим мне для лога `/var/log/dir1/her1/her1.log` нужно параметр `rotate` увеличить до 80 , я разумеется для этого делаю конфиг `/etc/logrotate.d/her1.conf` где пишу

```
    /var/log/dir1/her1/her1.log {
        missingok
        rotate 80
        postrotate
            /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        endscript
    }
```

После чего logrotate начинает ругаться на дубли, что говорит о том, что он не умеет переопределять параметры для логов. Собственно вопрос: А что делать в этой неловкой ситуации? Создавать для каждого лога свой конфиг - не вариант, тысячи их. Может у кого-нить есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Пока вижу только дурацкое решение. По дефолту rsyslog'ом записывать всё что прилетает по пути `/var/log/dir1/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%.log` и ротировать это всё по маске `/var/log/dir1/*/*log` , если понадобится для чего-то определённого указать отличные параметры, тогда создавать конфиг для rsyslog и писать уже для определённого хоста в `/var/log/dir2/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%.log` + создавать отдельный конфиг для этого хоста в /etc/logrotate.d/bla-bla-bla.conf с определённой маской в `/var/log/dir2/her1/her1.log` .
Дурацкое решение это потому, что в этом случае всё равно придётся плодить кучу конфигов :(

Может у кого-то будут идеи получше?